# C#: How to save image with best size for any screen size and any resolution

Tags: c#, image, picturebox

just wonder if anyone can give me concept to generate image with right size for any monitor size and resolution.

now i am in a situation where i have to generate several images from power point presentation each slides. i have to save each power point slides to each images. i will use the below code to do so.

```
PowerPoint.Presentation pptPresentation = pptApplication.Presentations.Open2007(FILE);
foreach (PowerPoint.Slide pptSlide in pptPresentation.Slides)
{
   pptSlide.Export(NEWNAME, "PNG", 1024, 768);
}
```

my problem is that i will show those images in my winform picturebox one after one like slide show. winform will load with maximize state and picturebox dock has been set to fill.

i do not know where my application will run. may be my application will run in 15 inch monitor or may be 17 inch or may be 21 inch. each pc may have different resolution. also my application may run in pc which is connected with big LCD TV as monitor.

i want to save each slide to image in such a way as a result when image will be shown through picturebox then image should be pixelated. this is my main concern. so please guide me how could i save each slide to image as a result image should be pixelated wherever it is shown irrespective of monitor size and resolution.

so tell me what height and width i should specify when will save each slide to image.

if possible please guide me with concept or sample code to achieve what i am after. thanks

Comment: _"i want to save each slide to image in such a way as a result when image will be shown through picturebox then image **should be** pixelated"_ - should there be a **not** in there?

Comment: The only way to save a bitmap image in a way that makes it look good on any display is to save it with a size bigger than any display it will ever appear on. And before you do that, let me warn you that that is a terrible idea.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean *"I want to save an image so that it looks great on all monitors without any pixelation"*, then that's **not** possible with raster images because by definition they are of a fixed spacial resolution.

If you want to save an image so that it looks fantastic irrespective of the output device then you should be using **vector graphics** such as that produced in *Adobe Illustrator*; *CorelDraw!* and the like.

Comment: It looks like he's exporting existing images from a PowerPoint presentation and wants to display those at scale which makes this question even worse.

Comment: @Equalsk oh dear...yes agreed :)

Answer (score 0):

As said by other ones, to keep actual resolution in every scale, you have to use vector formats. there are some options in save as dialog in powerpoint: `*.emf` or print/convert to `.pdf` file (but looks not so good at rendering, test it).

another way is to change the design page size in `Design > Page Setup` menu to a large size (but same aspect ration), this way you can get higher resolution pics.

Also see [Image Export of PPTTools](http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00052_Improve_PowerPoint-s_GIF-_BMP-_PNG-_JPG_export_resolution.htm#REG)